# save and update a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have two lists, rooms and beds.

```
rooms = ['r1', 'r2', 'r3', 'r4']
beds = ['b11', 'b12', 'b13', 'b21', 'b22', 'b31', 'b41', 'b42']
```

I create a dictionaries to keep track of every single element on the lists (I will need it after):

```
def create_dict():
    global clean_rooms
    clean_rooms = {}
    for room in rooms:
        clean_rooms[room] = 0

    global clean_beds
    clean_beds = {}
    for bed in beds:
        clean_beds[bed] = 0
```

I save my dictionaries:

```
fileName = "rooms list"
fileObject = open(fileName, 'w')   
pickle.dump(clean_rooms, fileObject) 
fileObject.close()

fileName = "beds list"
fileObject = open(fileName, 'w')   
pickle.dump(clean_beds, fileObject) 
fileObject.close()
```

Here is where I'm stuck. I want to create a function to choose a random bed and a random room from the dictionaries created before and add a unit to the values of the chosen keys in the dictionaries (rooms and beds).

After that I need to save again the dictionaries with the updated keys in order to use them when I call the function a second time, a third time and so on: This is my incomplete function:

```
def todo():
    fileName = "rooms list"
    fileObject =open(fileName, 'r')
    clean_rooms = pickle.load(fileObject)

    room = random.choice(list(clean_rooms))
    clean_rooms[room] += 1

    fileName = "beds list"
    fileObject =open(fileName, 'r')
    clean_beds = pickle.load(fileObject)

    bed = random.choice(list(clean_beds))
    clean_beds[bed] += 1

    fileName = "rooms list"
    fileObject = open(fileName, 'w')   
    pickle.dump(clean_rooms, fileObject) 
    fileObject.close()

    fileName = "beds list"
    fileObject = open(fileName, 'w')   
    pickle.dump(clean_beds, fileObject) 
    fileObject.close()
```

Solved! I'm stupid, I was calling the function to create the dictionary every time!

Comment: What exactly is the problem with what you have?

Comment: my dictionaries don't update at all!

Comment: Well you don't save them back to the file, as it stands!

Comment: Exactly the same way you do it when you create them, which is why I'm not sure what the problem is

Comment: ...that error message is *nowhere* in your question. Please edit it with the appropriate information (i.e. full error traceback).

Comment: Sorry. I edited the post with this info.

Comment: There is no way `room = random.choice(list(clean_rooms))` succeeds then `clean_rooms[room] += 1` fails with `NameError` on the next line. Are you absolutely sure this is exactly the code you are running?

Comment: Sorry my mistake! Updated post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would completely re-engineer this. Firstly, create functions to save to and load from files:

```
def pickle_dict(d, filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        pickle.dump(d, f)

def unpickle_dict(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return pickle.load(f)
```

Next, the function to create the original empty dictionaries:

```
def create_dict(keys):
    d = {}
    for key in keys:
        d[key] = 0
    return d
```

Now you can easily create the original files:

```
rooms = ['r1', 'r2', 'r3', 'r4']
room_file = "room_dict.txt"
pickle_dict(create_dict(rooms), room_file)
```

and create the function to randomly add to a room:

```
def dirty_room(room_file):
    rooms = unpickle_dict(room_file)
    room = random.choice(list(clean_rooms))
    clean_rooms[room] += 1
    pickle_dict(clean_rooms, room_file)
```

You can duplicate all of this for the `beds`.

Note I have not used `global` - everything needed is an explicit argument to the function. This makes development and testing much easier, as does lots of short functions with clear responsibilities.

Comment: How can it be? If it is declared as a global variable! clean_rooms[room] += 1
NameError: global name 'clean_rooms' is not defined

Comment: That's a totally different error! Where does that happen? Again, *please provide full traceback*.

Comment: Thanks a lot jonrsharpe!